# Cannot insert NULL value in column error in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, sql-insert

this is my query

```
insert into membre (code) 
select code = case when trig = '' then 'toto' else case when trig is null 'titi' end end
from test
```

I wanna insert this result to table test but that print me this error
. Can you helm me Please ?

Comment: Either make the table column nulable or prevent nulls from getting there in the first place.

Comment: i can't change table test

Comment: You need to cater for all scenarios or have a `else` block in your case. What if trig is neither empty string nor a null? You can also combine the inner case in with the outer one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want the following logic

```
insert into membre(code)
select case 
    when trig = '' then 'toto'
    when trig is null then 'titi'
    else trig
end
from test
```

This inserts `test(trig)` to `membre(code)`, while turning empty strings to `'toto'` and `null` values to `'titi'`.